# Expand sh variable(not Env) in file

Tags: go

**Can you expand a variable set in a sh script file**

In the following, FOO will not be printet - but if you uncomment `// os.Setenv("FOO", "A")`. Is there a way to expand the variable set within the script?

```
func TestExpandShVar(t *testing.T) {
    // os.Setenv("FOO", "A")
    cmdOne := exec.Command("sh", "-c", os.ExpandEnv("FOO=B\n\"VALUE:${FOO}\""))
    fmt.Println(cmdOne.Args[2])
}
```

Comment: Is the expected behavior, as described in the [doc](https://golang.org/pkg/os/#ExpandEnv): `References to undefined variables are replaced by the empty string`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`FOO=B` will be executed by the shell, and [`os.ExpandEnv()`](https://golang.org/pkg/os/#ExpandEnv) is a Go function call, and it will be executed *before* the command starts.

`os.ExpandEnv()` only analyzes the `string` passed to it to find `${var}` or `$var` patterns. It obviously does not interpret the shell command. So no, what you want is not possible without an interpreter.